Pagination in ASP.NET Core MVC
I have an issue with my pagination using ASP.NET Core 8. When the category has a few records (< 2500), the pagination works fine. It shows the pagination 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
When I have a lot of rows (> 2500), the pagination does not show properly. The pagination goes off the screen, the css style is not aligned, and the pagination does not start at 1. It does not matter if I show 10, 25, or 50 records per page (page size in the script), the same issue occurs.
public async Task<IActionResult> Category(int id, int page = 1)
{
    var category = await _context.Categories
                                 .Include(c => c.Subcategories)
                                 .ThenInclude(sc => sc.Recipes)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CategoryId == id);
 
    if (category == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var subcategories = category.Subcategories
                                .Select(sc => sc.SubcategoryName)
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList();

    var recipes = category.Subcategories
                          .SelectMany(sc => sc.Recipes)
                          .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                          .Take(PageSize)
                          .ToList();

    int totalRecipes = category.Subcategories
                               .SelectMany(sc => sc.Recipes)
                               .Count();

    ViewBag.CategoryID = id;
    ViewBag.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
    ViewBag.Subcategories = subcategories;
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
    ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecipes / PageSize);

    return View(recipes);
}  

<!-- Pagination Controls -->
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
               @if (ViewBag.CurrentPage > 1)
               {
                   <li class="page-item">
                       <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.CurrentPage - 1)">
                       &laquo;
                       </a>
                   </li>
               }

               @for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.TotalPages; i++)
               {
                   <li class="page-item @(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                       <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@i">@i</a>
                   </li>
               }

               @if (ViewBag.CurrentPage < ViewBag.TotalPages)
               {
                   <li class="page-item">
                       <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.CurrentPage + 1)">
                       &raquo;
                       </a>
                   </li>
               }
           </ul>
       </nav>
   </div>
</div>


You are writing ALL of the page numbers. When there are too many then it will flow outside of your DIV. Try writing only a few (+/- 5) or in 10-Steps.
@for (int i = Math.Max(1,page-5); i <= Math.Min(page+5,ViewBag.TotalPages); i++)
{
     <li class="page-item @(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
         <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@i">@i</a>
     </li>
}

The example shows -5 /+5 pages as numbers.
You could also mix this and go all out
@{
         var paginationList = new List<int>(9);
         var pageStepsBack = (int)page/3; //show 3 steps back in bigger jumps
         var pageStepsForth = (int)(ViewBag.TotalPages - page)/3; //show 3 steps forth in bigger jumps
               
         //if step > 1 then we write additional 3 steps with bigger jumps
         for (int i = 1,j=0;pageStepsBack > 1,j<3;i = i + pageStepsBack,j++)
                    paginationList.Add(i);
                   
         for (int i = -1; i < 2, i++)
         {
             var index = page + i;
             if (index > 0)      
                 paginationList.Add(index);
         }
                
          //if step > 1 then we write additional 3 steps with bigger jumps
          for (int i = page,j=0;pageStepsForth > 1,j<3;i = i + pageStepsForth, j++)
             paginationList.Add(i);

         foreach (var i in paginationList)
         {
             <li class="page-item @(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                 <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@i">@i</a>
             </li>
         }
}

There might be some edge cases, where only a few pages are shown, but I guess, this is a good start to work these out.

I think it makes more sense to use paged pagination, so that only a few page links are displayed at a time, like this
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
                <!-- this will be the previous button -->
                @if (ViewBag.CurrentPage > 1)
                {
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.CurrentPage - 1)">
                            &laquo;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }

                <!-- this will be the first page button -->
                @if (ViewBag.StartPage > 1)
                {
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="1">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">...</a></li>
                }

                <!-- these are the pages -->
                @for (int i = ViewBag.StartPage; i <= ViewBag.EndPage; i++)
                {
                    <li class="page-item @(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                        <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@i">@i</a>
                    </li>
                }

                <!-- this is a button for last page -->
                @if (ViewBag.EndPage < ViewBag.TotalPages)
                {
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">...</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@ViewBag.TotalPages">@ViewBag.TotalPages</a>
                    </li>
                }

                <!-- this will be the next button -->
                @if (ViewBag.CurrentPage < ViewBag.TotalPages)
                {
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" asp-action="Category" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.CategoryID" asp-route-page="@(ViewBag.CurrentPage + 1)">
                            &raquo;
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>

somethinng like this.

Here's a basic idea of how to show only 16 or so buttons plus tail(s) 1...buttons...end (some old code I used to use for inventory):
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.PaginatedInventory.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.PaginatedInventory.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var numberOfPages = Model.PaginatedInventory.TotalPages;
    var CurrentPageIndex = Model.PaginatedInventory.PageIndex;
    int CurrentLimit = Model.IntegerCurrentLimit;
    int start = ((CurrentPageIndex - 8) > 0) ? CurrentPageIndex - 8 : 0;
    int end = ((CurrentPageIndex + 8) < numberOfPages) ? CurrentPageIndex + 7 : numberOfPages;

}
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.PaginatedInventory.PageIndex - 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>

@if (numberOfPages > 20)
{
    @if (start > 0)
    {
        <a asp-page="./Index"
           asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
           asp-route-pageIndex="1"
           class="btn btn-default">
            1
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-default">...</button>
    }
    @for (var x = start; x < end; x++)
    {
        if (x + 1 == CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            <button class="btn btn-primary">@(x + 1)</button>
        }
        else
        {
            <a asp-page="./Index"
               asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
               asp-route-pageIndex="@(x + 1)"
               class="btn btn-default">
                @(x + 1)
            </a>
        }
    }
    @if (end < numberOfPages)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-default">...</button>
        <a asp-page="./Index"
           asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
           asp-route-pageIndex="@(numberOfPages)"
           class="btn btn-default">
            @(numberOfPages)
        </a>
    }    
}
else
{
    @for (var x = 0; x < numberOfPages; x++)
    {
        if (x + 1 == CurrentPageIndex)
        {
            <button class="btn btn-primary">@(x + 1)</button>
        }
        else
        {
            <a asp-page="./Index"
               asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
               asp-route-pageIndex="@(x + 1)"
               class="btn btn-default">
                @(x + 1)
            </a>
        }
    }
}
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-limit="@Model.CurrentLimit"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.PaginatedInventory.PageIndex + 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>

